# Avoid locking inside of boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, interprocess, boost-interprocess

I want to create a `managed_shared_memory` that is going to be created and written to by process A and read from by process B. So far I managed to implement the functionality I want, but I realized that when a process crashed during a `.find` or `.construct` operation, the mutex will not be unlocked (so it is not a robust mutex).
The [documentation says](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.making_ipc_easy.managed_memory_segment_int) that there is a way to disable the internal locking of the shared memory. This would be great because I want to use an `interprocess_condition` anyway.

> The synchronization type (MemoryAlgorithm::mutex_family) to be used in all allocation operations. This allows the use of user-defined mutexes or avoiding internal locking (maybe code will be externally synchronized by the user).

The problem is I am at a total loss on how to change the locking behavior of the `managed_shared_memory` object. I looked through its constructors but I cannot find a solution to this problem.

I am restricted to using boost 1.60 and I am writing for a Linux device, although any portable solution would be preferred since I am using boost anyway.

Comment: "This would be great because I want to use an interprocess_condition anyway." - except you will always have the race at process launch (or actually at segment open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is I am at a total loss on how to change the locking behavior of the managed_shared_memory object. I looked through its constructors but I cannot find a solution to this problem.

Okay, I think the choice is hard-coded - for good reason. Like I said in my comment there is no safe way to access managed memory segments from different processes without synchronization on the segment metadata.

Now, if you're absolutely sure you want to (you're in shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-with-enough-rope-to-hang-yourself territory) you should probably **manually** mount a managed external buffer:

> [Managed External Buffer: Constructing all Boost.Interprocess objects in a user provided buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer.managed_external_buffer)

You could of course still put it in an (unmanaged) `mapped_region` of *Mappable Object* (like `shared_memory_object`).

You can parameterize your managed external buffer as you wish, but the default already doesn't lock:

```
typedef basic_managed_external_buffer <
   char,
   rbtree_best_fit<null_mutex_family, offset_ptr<void> >,
   flat_map_index
   >  managed_external_buffer;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This has made me seriously reconsider my approach. I just wonder, if I do not use the user provided buffer approach, what would be good practice in dealing with the possibility of one process crashing while holding the mutex? I thought about putting the `construct` and `find` commands in their own thread with a timeout on the return, where I could destroy the management memory if the request for either one of those is not returning. Would you consider this additional complexity more sane than shooting myself in the foot? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not too sure. I think most people use an explicit named interprocess mutex - which still has the same problem of not being robust, but that can then be resolved in the occasion it matters by forcibly removing and recreating it. I remember this coming up a few times over the last ~decade on [SO] so a search for "interprocess robust" might help.

Comment: And yes, the solutions (workarounds?) I remember seeing online seemed to use a timeout AFAIR, and I do consider that a saner approach. Alternatively, you might see if you can find a robust lock for your platform.

Comment: Note that boost::interprocess::scoped_lock has a `timed_lock` member that can help with the timeout without introducing more thread synchronization pitfalls.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I am reading up on `boost::interprocess::scoped_lock` right now thank you!